# How to make CSS Template w3schools Content height 100%

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS Template from w3schools code below.

How do I make the content area 100% height of browser window?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>CSS Template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Style the top navigation bar */
    
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    /* Style the topnav links */
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    /* Change color on hover */
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    /* Style the content */
    
    .content {
      background-color: #ddd;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 200px;
      /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
    }
    /* Style the footer */
    
    .footer {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>CSS Template</h2>
    <p>A topnav, content and a footer.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with: `.content {height: 100vh;}` or `.content {height: 100%;}`, I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: 100% of what? 100% of window screen? try to set height 100% to body and html tag. And take a look to the Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax

Comment: I tried setting .content height to 100%

But I found I also had to set the parent to 100%

````html
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `min-height: 100vh`, this rule adds a minimum height of 100% of viewport height.

example:

```css
.content {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh; /* add minimum height of 100% */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting .content height to 100%

But I found I also had to set the parent to 100%

```html
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
      background-color: #ddd;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Setting both worked for me